# Unused import warning in Eclipse/PyDev although it is used

Tags: python, eclipse, scipy, pydev

I am importing a plotting package in my file like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and am using this import later on in my code successfully(!)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
```

However, Eclipse is telling me this: 
"Unused import: plt Found at: matplotlib.pyplot"

There might be a very simple solution for this, but I could not find it on the internet. I am new to Eclipse and PyDev, but there should be some way so that Eclipse recognized pyplot as plt?

Comment: It may sound dumb, but... if you remove the import it stops working? Is it the only place where you're importing ``matplotlib.pyplot as plt``?

Comment: I am not importing pyplot anywhere else in my file. If I remove the import plt.figure() does not work anymore.

Comment: If you do not show the complete source code none will be able to test and see how to fix your problem. Anyway it may also be a bug in PyDev.

Comment: @HyperCube in a simple script (if it's not one already), with just the ``import`` and ``fig = ... ``,  does this also happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel embarrassed. The comments from Ignacio and Bakurio already pointed at the right direction. In fact, next to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I am also importing

```
from pylab import *
```

These imports interfere with one another, since pylab is also importing pyplot. Remove the latter import results in no warning messages anymore in Eclipse. Next time I'll paste the full source code.

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem going to Project -> Properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH and click on "Force restore internat info".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed matplotlib 1.3.1 (Win 32 bit; Python 2.7.6). In my lib/site-packages/ folder there were actually two different matplotlib folders, one containing the actual code and binaries, and another one called matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7.egg-info. I simply deleted the one ending in ...egg-info and it worked. For an explanation, see this thread: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/ANN-matplotlib-1-3-0rc1-td41151.html.