# pydev shows Unused import warning though used in getattr as the first argument/object

Tags: python, pydev

flake8 correctly identifies the object as being used (sample code below) however the internal pydev interpreter does not. Pydev version is latest (6.2 as of writing)

```
from foo import bar # Shows unused import warning

...
getattr(bar, "xyz")
```

Update: this unused warning doesn't show when the file has just these two lines of code. also if I remove this import, the code breaks on bar not being defined so it does not seem to be getting imported in some other file.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13305929/1149933) answer makes me wonder; what else are you doing?  Could you post a little more code?  Does the issue exist in a file which _only_ contains your snippet?

Comment: @AdamBarnes The moment I remove the import, the code stops working so its not getting imported from elsewhere.

Comment: Fair enough, but does PyDev complain with only those two lines in your file?

Comment: @AdamBarnes, it does not complain with only those two lines

Comment: Then it follows that there's something else in your problem file that's the _real_ cause of the issue.  Try removing lines from the file to see if that fixes the problem, until you only have three lines left.  The two you posted, and the line causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure raw elimination like that should probably boil it down for any problem in a few hours. However, didn't work for the import statement removals I tried and then it was easier to use a # UnusedImport exception in pydev after that.

Comment: Well you could do a binary search and have it done in a couple minutes...  You're a computer scientist after all.